# Will installing Ubuntu from a CD delete my files?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

I am installing Ubuntu 12.04 from a CD-ROM. When I install, will the partition I give to Ubuntu be formatted for Ubuntu? Thanks!  I have Windows 7.

Comment: What is the existing OS on your machine? If it's and older Ubuntu version, you can upgrade via the installer and preserve existing data. Otherwise, you'll need to back up files before installing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends...!

During the installation of Ubuntu you'll be represented with maximum of three options to choose from.

**1. Installing alongside Windows**

If you already have Windows installed then you can install it alongside Windows, Your Windows installation will be safe and you'll be able to run booth operating systems.

**2. Replace Windows with Ubuntu**

In this case you'll lose every thing on your windows partition and won't be able to boot into Windows any more.

**3. Something else**

This option will let you choose any partition on your drives and that partition will be formatted. You can also create a new partition.

[image]

**For complete guide on how to install Ubuntu visit:**

- [Graphical Install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall) - Community Ubuntu Documentation

Answer (score 0):

When you install Ubuntu from the CD-ROM you should choose 'Install Ubuntu alongside Windows' and it will ask you to resize your current Windows partition to give space to Ubuntu. If everything goes well, you'll not loose any data in the process. There are a lot of guides on YouTube, I recommend you watching them... If you do, it will be a lot easier.
Also, you can always backup your important files if you are afraid of deleting them.

You should read [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot#Install_Ubuntu_after_Windows) and [this one](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall) if you still need more help.

Comment: Also to add to your answer, if you don't already have backups of your important files, Your Doing It Wrong (tm). This has nothing to do with installing Ubuntu and everything to do with protecting yourself and your interests (in this case, your important files)